# clickable transparent window in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron

I am trying to make a transparent window in Electron. So far, I'm able to solve and find the solutions to every problem except for this one.
I'm trying to make a transparent full-size browser window in electron which stays always on top of other windows so that I can draw the rectangle using the mouse to mimic screen selection.

This is my browserWindow

```
const createCanvasWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window for screen selection.

  canvasWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    skipTaskbar: true,
    transparent: true,
    fullscreen: true,
    show: false,
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    frame: false,
    // opacity: 0.1,
    focusable: true,
    acceptFirstMouse: true,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, './preloaders/canvas_preload.js')
    }
  });

  // canvasWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(false);
  // canvasWindow.setFocusable(true);

  canvasWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/templates/index.html`)
};
```

And inside the `index.html` script I have a JS function like this

```
document.onmousemove = function (e) {
            setMousePosition(e); // function to get mouse cordinates
        }
```

I'm able to create the transparent window but this doesn't catch any mouse click or mouse move event but the window beneath it does.
And if I change the `opacity` to any value other than 0, I'm getting mouse events.
I also tried to set `canvasWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(false);` and `canvasWindow.setFocusable(true);` but neither of them worked.

From the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winsetopacityopacity-windows-macos) `opacity` doesn't work on Linux.

How can I make a fully transparent window which catches all mouse click move and keyboard events?

I'm using Electron 17.1.1, Windows 10, Node 16.14, and npm 7.19.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch mousemove events you can remove `show: false` and add `canvasWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true, { forward: true });`